# NextJS Website Breaks On Production But Works Fine On Development

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, antd

I have been developing an application using NextJS with Typescript and has encountering this problem. I am not new, but I have never encountered this problem while I have done many projects like this and hosted them.

So, in simple words, I created a horizontal menu (main menu) that has contents inside of it. But when i switch around on the main menu, the app basically breaks (this occurs when it's hosted and works without errors when I run it locally). Although navigating around the side menus works fine.

Hosted Website Link: https://inflow-temp.vercel.app/

Demo Video Link: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/11478402?key=c4d65a557445434a7823230cb3cbbfb0

Clone to check it locally.
Repo Link: https://gitlab.com/ettadevs/inflow-temp

[image]

I am not fetching data from the internet nor mapping anything. I changed it dynamic routing hoping that would fix it, but still encountering the problem on production(hosted).

I have also tried hosting it on netlify just in case if it was vercel.com that was causing the problem, and yet I have had no luck in fixing this problem.

I have scoured the internet looking for answers, but found none.

I don't understand what is causing the problem or how to fix it. Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be caused by SWC, when I remove `swcMinify: true` from `next.config.js` I see no errors after building the project. There is a chance that this is caused by some dependency not working correctly with SWC minification. For now just disable SWC until it gets solved.

You can follow this [discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/30237) about SWC minify where other devs encountered similar issues to yours.

Comment: thanks for the answer. it worked even though i dont know why 
and if you would kindly upvote the question so that others might also see this answer, it would be helpful